# What is the difference between "derrochador," "despilfarrador," "manirroto," and "malgastador"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, adjetivos, sinónimos

I am especially interested in the differences between these four words (as well as any other significant synonyms), especially when they are used to mean "wasteful."

I haven't done much research on this, but I did at least consult the *Diccionario de la lengua española* and *WordReference.com*.  Other than seeing that "derrochador" as a translation for "spendthrift" is now considered "dated," I didn't see a whole lot to distinguish these four words.

I forget what I originally wanted to say, but it had to do with people.  To leave you with an example to work with, which of the four words would be best in the following sentence:

> Anyone can be a bit wasteful from time to time.

Under other circumstances, I'd do more research before posting this, such as exploring frequencies and collocations, but I can barely keep my eyes open right now, so, this time, I'll see what interesting answers you native speakers or professors of Spanish might provide.

---

**¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "derrochador", "despilfarrador", "manirroto" y "malgastador"?**

Me interesan especialmente las diferencias entre estas cuatro palabras (así como cualquier otro sinónimo significativo), sobre todo cuando se utilizan para significar "wasteful".

No he investigado mucho al respecto, pero al menos he consultado el *Diccionario de la lengua española* y *WordReference.com*.  Aparte de ver que "derrochador" como traducción de "spendthrift" se considera ahora "anticuado", no vi mucho para distinguir estas cuatro palabras.

He olvidado lo que quería decir en un principio, pero tenía que ver con las personas. Para dejarte un ejemplo con el que trabajar, cuál de las cuatro palabras quedaría mejor en la siguiente frase:

> Todo el mundo puede ser un poco [wasteful] de vez en cuando.

En otras circunstancias, investigaría más antes de publicar esto, por ejemplo, explorando frecuencias y colocaciones, pero apenas puedo mantener los ojos abiertos porque estoy muy cansado, así que, esta vez, veré qué respuestas interesantes pueden publicar los hablantes nativos o los profesores de español.

Comment: The verb desperdiciar is to waste but there is no adjective. Todo el mundo puede desperdiciar dinero o comida de vez en cuando. None of the others is used in everyday speech for wasteful except despilfarrador.  Also, tirar comida in some contexts.

Comment: @Lambie derrochador and manirroto are used "in every day speech". Despilfarrador, not so much. Cheers from Spain.

Comment: Lisa, do you need a "negative" word for your sentence? What about a positive one like "espléndido" or "generoso"? It depends on the rest of the context.

Comment: @RubioRic  Well, the topic was recycling, more specifically, what we were doing to save the planet through conservation methods.  I suppose I could have mentioned the _esfuerzos espléndidos_ of others or, even the _generosidad_ of some, but that wouldn't have expressed what I was attempting to say.  Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Comment: No, no, those words don't suit your context. Maybe you should add that information to the question.

Comment: @RubioRic  Another good suggestion, but I'm content with the answers already given and perhaps with less specificity the full thread may serve more people — those interested in a good translation of "wasteful" outside of just contexts related to recycling or conservation methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Ha considerado [**pródigo**](https://dle.rae.es/pr%C3%B3digo)

> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que desperdicia y consume su hacienda en gastos inútiles, sin medida ni razón. U. t. c. s.

y [**prodigalidad**](https://dle.rae.es/prodigalidad?)?

> 1. f. Profusión, desperdicio, consumo de la propia hacienda, gastando excesivamente.

No son de uso cotidiano, pero si muy conocidas. Están recogidas, además de en el DLE, en el [Código Civil español](https://www.mundojuridico.info/la-declaracion-de-prodigalidad/) y en el Nuevo Testamento [(Parábola del hijo pródigo)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A1bola_del_hijo_pr%C3%B3digo).

Otra alternativa podría ser [**gastoso**](https://dle.rae.es/gastoso?):

> 1. adj. Que gasta mucho.

Y, aunque menos utilizada hoy día, está [**despendedor**](https://dle.rae.es/despendedor):

> 1. adj. desus. Que gasta con exceso, malbaratando y disipando la hacienda. Era u. t. c. s.

Comment: Me gusta mucho su respuesta.  Ha enriquecido mi vocabulario y ha citado fuentes.  Por esas razones y por el hecho de que es debutante de esta comunidad, le otorgo la marca verde.  Bien hecho y por ello le doy la bienvenida.

Answer (score 1):

"Derrochador" means a person with a lot of money that spends it without thinking.
"Despilfarrador" is similar, but the person doesn't necessarily have a lot of money.
"Malgastador" means a person who wastes money in a bad way or in bad things.

The 3 words are mostly used with reference to money.

So a possible translation of your example referring to money could be:

> Todo el mundo puede ser un poco malgastador de vez en cuando.

Another form that could refer to money or food:

> Todo el mundo puede desperdiciar de vez en cuando.